# How do you get strip RTF formatting and get actual string value using DXL in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors

I am trying to get the values in "ID" column of DOORS and I am currently doing this
string ostr=richtext_identifier(o)

When I try to print ostr, in some modules I get just the ID(which is what I want). But in other modules I will get values like "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1256\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\froman\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}} {*\generator Riched20 10.0.17134}\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\f0\fs20\lang1033 SS_\f1\fs24 100\par } " This is the RTF value and I am wondering what the best way is to strip this formatting and get just the value.

Perhaps there is another way to go about this that I am not thinking of as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the ID column of DOORS is actually a composite- DOORS builds it out of the Module level attribute 'Prefix' and the Object level attribute 'Absolute Number'.

If you wish to grab this value in the future, I would do the following (using your variables)

```
string ostr = ( module ( o ) )."Prefix" o."Absolute Number" ""
```

This is opposed to the following, which (despite seeming to be a valid attribute in the insert column dialog) **WILL NOT WORK**.

```
string ostr = o."Object Identifier" ""
```

Hope this helps!

Comment response: You should not need the module name for the code to work. I tested the following successfully on DOORS 9.6.1.10:

```
Object o = current

string ostr = ( module ( o ) )."Prefix" o."Absolute Number" ""

print ostr
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the **identifier** function, which takes an Object as input parameter, and returns the identifier as a plain (not RTF) string:

**Declaration**
string identifier(Object o)
**Operation**
Returns the identifier, which is a combination of absolute number and module prefix, of object o as a string.

The optimal solution somewhat depends on your underlying requirement for retrieving the object ID.